# Anyone know about good WP plugin for news content- slider?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i need to put something like below to my custom WP theme,
Basically it will get post image,title and description and render as below,
you can scroll through each post.

Do you guys know any good plugin to do this?

http://awesomescreenshot.com/069u8i3d3

Thanks Guys.I

Comment: Since you're new, I introduce you to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your example is using an 'Infinite Carousel'-type script. I don't think there are any plugins available that do the scripting for you, but you could check out some demos by the creator here: http://sroucheray.org/blog/jquery-plugins/jquery-infinite-carousel/ as well as download it from Google code here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-infinite-carousel/